# Prioritization of output by more than one factor in List

Tags: list, unity-game-engine

```
public Transform m_targetPos;
public List<Transform> l_targetList = new List<Transform>();

private void GetPriority()
{
    l_targetList = l_targetList.OrderBy(x => Vector3.Distance(_path.m_start.position, 
        (x.transform == _PC.transform) ? x.transform.position + new Vector3(0, 10, 0) : x.transform.position))
        .ToList();
    m_targetPos = l_targetList[0];
}
```

Here I have a method to output a single Transform to store in m_targetPos to feed another method for other functions like targeting for AoE attack. As of now, it's sorted by a factor(distance from a point called _path.m_start.position) and that's the basic function I intended this to work.

However, how can I add another distinguishing factor from here?

Let me explain what I want:

There are two tag; tagA and tagB. If in List l_targetList objectAwithTagA has a distance of 10 and objectBwithTagB has a distance of 7 the method GetPriority() will store objectBwithTagB due to the distance. However, since tagA is prioritized by my intention I want GetPriority() to ignore(or compensate some amount) of the distance factor to prioritize object with tagA.

I feel like I totally blew the comprehension here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just `x => Vector3.Distance(...)` do something along the lines of `x => Vector3.Distance(...) * CalculateTagFactor(x)`. To have no effect from the tag, just have CalculateTagFactor return 1. To have it ignore anything with a tag, return `float.NaN` or `float.PositiveInfinity`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, the CalculateTagFactor(x) must be in range of 0 to 1 and smaller has greater effect, correct?

Comment: `return 0.5` = treat any distance with this tag as half as far. `return 2` = treat any distance with this tag as twice as far. You could go as high as you want or into negative numbers, but likely you'll want to be around 1 most of the time.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. it was to extend the float value(distance) by the modifier. Thanks!